# XSL parsing issue for-each tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

My XSL not working with parameter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="reportname" />
<xsl:param name="quarter" />
<xsl:param name="menteename" />

<xsl:template match="AllReports" >
<xsl:for-each select="./Report[@Name=$reportname]" >
    <table border="0" class="dottedlines" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">

    <xsl:for-each select="Record[@Period=$quarter] and ($menteename)] >

<tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Entry">
 <td><xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/></td>
               </xsl:for-each>
</tr>

    </xsl:for-each>
</table>

    </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My XSL working with Hard coded values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="reportname" />
<xsl:param name="quarter" />
<xsl:param name="menteename" />

<xsl:template match="AllReports" >
<xsl:for-each select="./Report[@Name=$reportname]" >
    <table border="0" class="dottedlines" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">

    <xsl:for-each select="Record[@Period=$quarter] and (Entry= 'Dhirde, Govinda' or Entry= 'Vaze, Kedar')] >

<tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Entry">
 <td><xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/></td>
               </xsl:for-each>
</tr>

    </xsl:for-each>
</table>

    </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am passing the value of variable $menteename = "Entry= 'Dhirde, Govinda' or Entry= 'Vaze, Kedar'". But the hard coded thing  works good not the parameter one. I have found that there is some issue with the XSL parsing that it reads tags within the parameter value. Is this causing the problem. How can I make this work?

Comment: Sorry while uploading code i have entered one closing ']' extra. It dosen't work with <xsl:for-each select="Record[@Period=$quarter and ($menteename)]"> and works with <xsl:for-each select="Record[@Period=$quarter and (Entry= 'Dhirde, Govinda' or Entry= 'Vaze, Kedar')]">

Answer (score 0):

Well we really need to know which type of parameter value and which value you pass in to the stylesheet, in particular as your question is tagged as `xslt-2.0` where you should have the possibility to pass in a plain string value but as well a sequence of strings.

Assuming you pass in a sequence of strings `'Dhirde, Govinda', 'Vaze, Kedar'` you can simply test

```
  Entry = $menteename
```

in your predicate.

If you pass in a plain string which contains several names then of course the strings needs to be split into individual values. As the values already contain commas a different separator is needed e.g. with the string value passed in being `'Dhirde, Govinda|Vaze, Kedar'`, you could use

```
Entry = tokenize($menteename, '\|')
```

in your predicate.

Assuming you use XSLT 1.0 and can't use or don't want to use an extension function to split up the parameter's string value you can use a check like

```
contains(concat('|', $menteename, '|'), concat('|', Entry, '|'))
```

This assumes the `Entry` element contains a single value like `Vaze, Kedar` and you pass in a `bar` separated list of names e.g.  `'Dhirde, Govinda|Vaze, Kedar'` as the parameter value, then that check does

```
contains('|Dhirde, Govinda|Vaze, Kedar|', '|Vaze, Kedar|')
```

Comment: Well my suggestion is XPath/XSLT 2.0 for which you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime. The error message rather sounds as if you use XSLT inside a Mozilla browser like Firefox which only supports XSLT 1.0. So you first need to clarify which XSLT processor respectively which XSLT version you want to use.

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0. Can you please help me on this

Comment: Well with XSLT 1.0 you have two options, either use an extension function if your XSLT processor supports one or use a check like `contains(concat('|', $menteename, '|'), Entry)`. I will edit my post and show that in the post in addition to this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Variables hold values, not expressions. You can't replace an expression lilke (@x = 3) with a variable whose value is the string "@x = 3". To do that kind of thing you need an extension that evaluates an XPath expression supplied as a string, for example saxon:evaluate(), or in XSLT 3.0 xsl:evaluate.